# How to use ScrollFire Demo in Materialize Css with react

Tags: reactjs, materialize

```js
var options = [
    {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 50, callback: 'Materialize.toast("This is our ScrollFire Demo!", 1500 )' },
    {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 205, callback: 'Materialize.toast("Please continue scrolling!", 1500 )' },
    {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 400, callback: 'Materialize.showStaggeredList("#staggered-test")' },
    {selector: '#image-test', offset: 500, callback: 'Materialize.fadeInImage("#image-test")' }
  ];
  Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

How can i use this Materialize.scrollFire() with a react. In my **App.js** file looks like this-

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import M from 'materialize-css'

import Navbar from './components/navbar'

class App extends Component {

   componentDidMount() {
     const options = [
       {
         selector: '.main-text',
         offset: 0,
         callback: function(el) {
           Materialize.fadeInImage(el)
         }
       }
     ]

     Materialize.scrollFire(options)
   }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I call Materialize.scrollFire() function in componentDidMount() LifeCycle then it's show **Materialize is not defiened** But I already **import M from 'materialize-css'**. If i change M to Materialize like **import Materialize from 'materialize-css'** then it will show the **Materialize is not defined.** How i **implementation this Materialize.scrollFire()** in a correct way

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of it?

Comment: yes here is may link---

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ygmlyt

Comment: which package you are using?

Comment: Materialize-css

Comment: Seems that you are missing package import in your link

Comment: ok i added this packege link -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ygmlyt